# Unable to bind dropdowlist using jQuery in asp .net page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I have created a page in asp .net added jquery reference in it and have web service hosted on another server. I have dropdown which i bind using jQuery, but its not getting bind and i also not able to identify what is the error. My code.

```
<script src="Script/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hf" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#ddl').append(
                $('<option></option>').val('0').html('Please Wait...')                    
            );
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://***.*.1.165:91/MastersService.asmx/GetDocTypeList",
            data: "{}",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError
        });

        // for get selected value from code behind
        $('#ddl').change(function () {
            $('#hf').val($('#ddl').val());
        });

    });

    function OnSuccess(data) {
        $('#ddl').empty();
        var d = data.d;
        var dropdown = $('#ddl');
        for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            dropdown.append(
                 $('<option></option>').val(d[i].docCode.toString()).html(d[i].docName.toString())
                );
        }
        //for keep data after postback
        $('#ddl').val($('#hf').val());
    }
    function OnError() {
        alert("Failed!");
    }

</script>
```

Webmethod..

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MastersService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{ 
    [WebMethod]
    public List<DocType> GetDocTypeList()
    {

        DataTable dt = MM.DocumentTypeList();
        List<DocType> doctype = new List<DocType>();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DocType objst = new DocType();
                objst.docCode = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["docCode"]);
                objst.docName = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["docName"]);
                doctype.Insert(i, objst);
            }

        }
        return doctype;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please tell me how to get the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using ASP.NET and `ddl` is a server control you need to use [`Control.ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx).

`<%= ddl.ClientID %>` will Gets the control ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET.

*Use*

```
$("#<%= ddl.ClientID %>").change(function() {
    //Your code
});
```

OR

You can use [`ClientIDMode.Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) mode

*like*

```
   <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hf" runat="server" />
    </td>
```

Then you can simply use `$('#ddl')`

Comment: Yes i am using asp .net, but i am not using any master page so i do not need to use Control.ClientID.

Comment: @Raghubar, Control.ClientID has nothing to do with master page it `Gets the control ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET.`

Comment: this my page source. check it. <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="ddl" id="ddl">

<option value="0">Please Wait...</option></select>
                <input type="hidden" name="hf" id="hf">
            </td>
        </tr>

Comment: You don't need `Control.ClientID` with HTML controls